# Error: Cannot find entry file ./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js in any of the roots:

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

I keep receiving this error when running my App.js for React Native that was working perfectly well before I attempted installing Victory charts. Somehow something broke and after over three hours of work I am unable to figure out a solution. I have tried everything I could find on the web including uninstalling watchman, reinstalling watchman, reverting to React Native 0.55.4, some other recommended commands. Nothing is working.I am so confused.

Comment: Are you developing for IOS?

Comment: @Reza primarily but would eventually like to include Android

Answer (score 1):

$ yarn add react-native-scripts

This helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other library may hurt the installation part of your package. To solve this issue on IOS you need to add its library like below:

First do 'yarn add react-native-scripts'. In the case that it dose't work continue other steps.

1-Go to the node module of your project and find the package folder and find the ios file inside it.

2- Then drag it into ‘library’ section of your xcode. (It is the subset of your project folders)

3- Then go to ‘build phase’ and in the ‘Link binary with libraries’ add it there by clicking on the plus sign

4- Then in some cases you need to add the correct path of the ios file inside your node module in the xcode. To do that you should go to ‘build setting’ section in the xcode and search header there. Then you need to add the path there below other paths.

5- Then clear everything (cmd+shift+k) and then finally compile it.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: I'm unsure how to go about this. I am currently looking in my node_modules folder and there isn't even a "react-native-scripts" folder

Comment: Also I am coding in Sublime Text so I don't know if that affects how to execute your answer

Comment: @JoelHochman: That is the point... it should be exist there... can you do it again: npm i react-native-scripts or yarn add react-native-scripts

Comment: you are currently the best human on this planet! thank you so much. Now I have another error about Expo SDK needing to Expo to run, to fix.

Comment: @JoelHochman: Thanks, if I am that person that you told please accept my answer as the correct answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the "crna-entry.js" file does exist in the roots and my project should work (nothing have been modified from last time when it does work).

After hours searching, finally I figured out the reason:

**the packager's directory checking is case-sensitive and in windows terminal the drive "c:/" will not be auto-corrected to "C:/" which will lead to error.**

Hope this will help someone who gets the same error.
Below is the full error message:

> The development server returned response error code:404 Cannot find
>
> entry file node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js
> in any of the roots:

Comment: Thanks for the response but this was not the solution for me.